# How to configure functions in Vue 2 project from being obfuscated during build

Tags: javascript, function, vuejs2, vuex, obfuscation

I have a couple functions (running in a custom webview browser) that serve as hooks and need to be declared in my js code. Unfortunately these functions seem to be obfuscated during the build of my Vue (2.6.11) project and therefore no longer function as hooks. Is there a way (possibly in vue.config.js) that I can select certain function names from being obfuscated during build?

As an addition to the question, is it possible to declare these functions in a vuex module or main.js file? If not, I am assuming I will need to include these under the created() or mounted() lifecycle hooks.

Note: currently the only workaround I found is to include the functions in a script tag in index.html found in the public folder.

Comment: Can you write them in their own JS module then import them into Vue where you need them? Then you can import the module into `main.js` or `index.html` or wherever (provided they don't need transpiling).

Comment: That is a bit of a cleaner way to implement this then including it in html. However I am wondering if there is a vue(centric) way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to vue.config.js seems to have resolved my issue (with slight side effects):

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization.minimizer("terser").tap((args) => {
        const { terserOptions } = args[0];
        terserOptions.keep_fnames = true;
        return args;
    });
}
```

This prevents all functions from being uglified, in turn keeps the function names from changing. The setback is that none of the functions are now uglified and the minified/partially obfuscated build is easier to figure out.